# Probability to win at least 1 time, playing 3 times.

Tags: probability

I have this problem:

> In a game, the probability of win is $1/3$ and of lose is $2/3$, ¿What
>   is the probabilty of win at least 1 prize playing 3 times?

The probability of win at least 1 prize, playing 3 times is the same of no win, that is: $(2/3)^3 = 8/3^3$

Now, the long way would be:

The probability of winning at least 1 price is equal to:

P(win 1 prize) + P(win 2 prize) + P(win 3 prize), that is:

P(win 1 prize) have 3 different ways: WLL, LLW, LWL(W = win, L = lose) and the probabilty for each one is $1/3 * 2/3 * 2/3 = (4/3^3)$ and since they are 3 different ways, so is: $3 *(4/3^3) = 4/3^2$

P(win 2 prize) have 3 different ways: WWL, WLW, LWW. = $3*(1/3 * 1/3 * 2/3) =  2/3^2$

P(win 3 prize) have only one way: WWW = $(1/3^3)$

adding the probabilities: $2/3^2 + 4/3^2 + 1/3^3 = 19/3^3$, but this result is different of $8/3^3$ that is the result of *no win*.

Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your arithmetic is correct. The problem is a logical error in the opening statement:

> "The probability of win at least 1 prize, playing 3 times is the same of no win, that is: $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3=\frac{8}{3^3}$"

It is not the same. Winning at least once and not winning at all are **compliments**. The outcomes are mutually exclusive and encompass all possibilities. Therefore, their probabilities should sum to 1. Solving the resulting equation gives the shortcut you are looking for.

$$P(A) + P(A^{c}) = 1$$

Comment: Yes, was my mistake, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Probability of win at least one time isn't the same as probability of no win, it's one minus probability of no win. And indeed $\frac{19}{3^3}$ and $\frac{8}{3^3}$ sums to $1$.